# How to search for libraries with less than three characters?

Tags: artifactory, conan

In the artifactory search bar it is only possible to search for libraries with more than three characters. This is pretty bad for libraries like qt which are not to be found, even if they are uploaded.

How does search work for these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory has a property in $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/var/etc/artifactory.system.properties named: artifactory.search.archive.minQueryLength and by default, it is 3 and that's where the UI gets the minimum value.

Searching libraries with less than 3 characters is available only for admin users.
For non-admin users, the workaround is to be specific.

For example qt package will usually be described with the word qt so the search can be:

> qt description:qt

Or if you know the package type that you're looking for, for example, conan qt package you can search:

> qt pkgType:conan